# Multithreading and recursion together

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, parallel-processing

I have recursive code that processes a tree structure in a depth first manner.  The code basically looks like this:

```
function(TreeNode curr) 
{
    if (curr.children != null && !curr.children.isEmpty()) 
    {
        for (TreeNode n : curr.children) 
    {
            //do some stuff
            function(n);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        //do some other processing
    }
}
```

I want to use threads to make this complete faster.  Most of the time is spent traversing so I don't want to just create a thread to handle "the other processing" because it doesn't take that long.  I think I want to fork threads at "do some stuff" but how would that work?

Comment: So the order of processing isn't important? The children may get processes in a random order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a good case for [Fork/Join framework](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) which is to be included into Java 7. As a standalone library for use with Java 6 it can be downloaded [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html).

Something like this:

```
public class TreeTask extends RecursiveAction {
    private final TreeNode node;
    private final int level;

    public TreeTask(TreeNode node, int level) {
        this.node = node;
        this.level = leve;
    }

    public void compute() {
        // It makes sense to switch to single-threaded execution after some threshold
        if (level > THRESHOLD) function(node);

        if (node.children != null && !node.children.isEmpty()) {
            List<TreeTask> subtasks = new ArrayList<TreeTask>(node.children.size());
            for (TreeNode n : node.children) {
                // do some stuff
                subtasks.add(new TreeTask(n, level + 1));
            }
            invokeAll(subtasks); // Invoke and wait for completion
        } else {
            //do some other processing
        }
    }
}

...
ForkJoinPool p = new ForkJoinPool(N_THREADS);
p.invoke(root, 0);
```

The key point of fork/join framework is work stealing - while waiting for completion of subtasks thread executes other tasks. It allows you to write algorithm in straightforward way, while avoiding problems with thread exhausting as a naive apporach with `ExecutorService` would have.

Comment: I've updated my post, I definitely want to use this fork framework but not sure how it fits in

Comment: last line must be `p.invoke(new TreeTask(root, 0));`

Comment: Note that if subtasks are created faster than they are executed by worker threads, the submission queue will overflow and you get a _RejectedExecutionException("Queue capacity exceeded")_. I'm looking for a solution for that problem...

Answer (score 3):

In the `// do some stuff` code block where you work on the individual Node, what you could do instead is submit the Node to some sort of [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (in the form of a `Runnable` which will work on the Node).

You can configure the `ExecutorService` that you use to be backed by a pool of a certain number of threads, allowing you to decouple the "handling" logic (along with logic around creating threads, how many to create, etc) from your tree-parsing logic.

Comment: so in that case, I am not traversing the tree using multiple threads.  I traverse the tree using one thread?

Comment: "`ExecutorService` that you use to be backed by a pool of a *certain number of threads*" hm... I wouldn't do that. Since we have dependencies between tasks it might cause deadlock. Or you must pay extreme attention to the order tasks are submitted.

Comment: Yes. Which part of this work are you trying to make concurrent - parsing the tree (which is simply walking through a data structure already in memory) or the work on it? If the former, then this might not help that much.

Comment: @pavelrappo where does the questions state that there are dependencies between tasks here? I'm answering based on what is in the question only.

Comment: I guess I didn't really think about which part I wanted to make concurrent.  It seems like doing a multithreaded traversal with some amount of processing is something that would be fairly common and I thought there might be a standard way to do it, a best practice if you will

Comment: There aren't dependencies between the "processing"

Comment: @JPC @matt b -- sorry guys. But there usually are. I am always trying to be prepared to the worst thing ^)

Comment: So I wrote the code so that the tree traversal is on the main thread and whenever I "process" a leaf node I pull a worker thread from the pool.  The processing is actually very simple and not that intensive so I don't gain much.  The traversal is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that the processing only happens at the leaf nodes and that the actual recursion of the tree doesn't take a long time.

I would have the caller thread do the recursion and then a `BlockingQueue` of workers that process the leafs via a thread-pool.  I'm not handling the `InterruptedException` in a couple of places here.

```
public void processTree(TreeNode top) {
    final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(MAX_NUM_QUEUED);
    // create a pool that starts at 1 threads and grows to MAX_NUM_THREADS
    ExecutorService pool =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, MAX_NUM_THREADS, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue,
            new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
                public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor e) {
                    queue.put(r);  // block if we run out of space in the pool
                }
            });
    walkTree(top, pool);
    pool.shutdown();
    // i think this will join with all of the threads
    pool.awaitTermination(WAIT_TILL_CHILDREN_FINISH_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
private void walkTree(final TreeNode curr, ExecutorService pool) {
    if (curr.children == null || curr.children.isEmpty()) {
        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                processLeaf(curr);
            }
        });
        return;
    }
    for (TreeNode child : curr.children) {
        walkTree(child, pool);
    }
}
private void processLeaf(TreeNode leaf) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The traversal is actually the bottleneck.  The work done on the nodes is actually not that difficult

Comment: Huh.  That's interesting.  Unless it truly is a monster tree, I'm not sure the threading is going to make a whole bunch of difference considering the memory contention.

Comment: Since java-ee is not supporting ForkJoinPool I am thinking of adopting your approach. One thing I did not clear understand about this code was  - "only one thread for recursion"? Where is that restriction?

Comment: The `walkTree(...)` method is run by the thread that also calls `processTree(...)`.  That's the thread that submit the jobs for the leaf processing @donlys.  I'll edit my answwer.

Comment: I came across a hurdle while using this approach in java-ee: I can't use pool.shutdown() or pool.awaitTermination.