# Using recursive functions in conjunction with threads (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

After reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) tutorial on java concurrency objects and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517413/multithreading-and-recursion-together) question on a similar topic, I don't understand how the `fork/join` framework can help with recursive methods. In my case, I want to browse a number of sections and their threads on an online forum:

```
 private void browseSection(Filter filter, WebClient webClient, String sectionUrl) {
        if(sectionUrl == null)
            return;
try {
            HtmlPage sectionPage = webClient.getPage(sectionUrl);
            // Get sections
            List<DomNode> sections = (List<DomNode>) sectionPage.getByXPath(forumTemplate.getXpathElements().get(forumTemplate.XPATH_GET_SECTIONS));
            if(sections == null)
                return;
            for (DomNode section : sections) {
                // Retrieve the url of the subsection
                String subsectionUrl = section.getNodeValue();
                // Go recursively in each subsection
                browseSection(filter, webClient, subsectionUrl);
            }
            // Get threads from section
            List<DomNode> threadsInSection = (List<DomNode>) sectionPage.getByXPath(forumTemplate.getXpathElements().get(forumTemplate.XPATH_GET_THREADS));
            // Browse threads
            for (DomNode threadInSection : threadsInSection) {
                browseThread(filter, webClient,
                        sectionUrl, threadInSection.getNodeValue());
            }
            // Go to the next section page
            DomNode nextPage = (DomNode) sectionPage.getFirstByXPath(forumTemplate.getXpathElements().get(forumTemplate.XPATH_GET_THREADS_NEXT_PAGE));

            String linkToNextSectionPage = nextPage.getNodeValue();

            // Browse the next page with threads from that section
            browseSection(filter, webClient, linkToNextSectionPage);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

How can the work of browsing through multiple sections (repeated calls of `browserSection()`) be split between more threads?

If more threads are created and launched in the `browseSection()` method, then the number of used threads may grow exponentially as there are more nested sections. Can `fork/join` offer an upper bound on the number of worker threads?

Answer (score 0):

In every call of browseSection you call it with a different url. That can be easily processed on a different thread. You probably don't want to create a new thread for each call, but you can have a pool of executors that can execute those browseSection calls independently, parallelly.

Comment: The thing is that each call changes the state of the method. There can be an arbitrary number of sections stored within each other (sectio--> ... --> section). Threads are processed when the sections have reached their maximum depth, from the highest to the lowest depth.

Comment: Not every algorithm can be processed parallely. But the state of the `method` is not your concern, that's in the stack and that's the whole point of recursive algorithms. The problem would be if it changed the state of the object (this). Here the only suspicios call I see is browseThread()

Comment: Browse thread only updates the status of a synchronized object shared between all threads. The problem is that I don't where to parallelize in the code. I cannot create threads before calling browseSection() and only inside it. But then I can't control the final number of threads that will be created since I can't have an upper bound over the threads with 'basic' multithreading primitives.

Comment: Look at the links in your question and my answer. You can use Executors that execute the submitted jobs on a predefined number of threads in a pool. You submit your jobs, and the executor takes care of creating the thread